# Objective C saving user credentials into a singleton and

Tags: ios, objective-c

My I idea is to save the user credentials into to a singleton and use this singleton for authentication on a server.

But some how my typed in user name as well as password is always empty and I dont know why...

What I do

singleton called session in my case

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString*UserName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString*Password;

+(Session *)getSession;

+(Session *)getSession
{
    static Session* theSingelton = nil;
    @synchronized([ Session class])
    {
        if (theSingelton == nil) {
            theSingelton = [[Session alloc]init];
    }
    return theSingelton;
    }
}
```

Nothing special more or less standard.

Here is my login that I call in my viewdidload

```
-(void)showLoginPormt{
    UIAlertView *login = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Log-in" message:@"Please enter your credentials" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Log in", nil];

    login.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    UITextField *tf = [login textFieldAtIndex:0];
    tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

    [login show];
```

And this is how i save the "User name" and the "Password" into my singleton

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
        NSString *userName  = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        NSString *passWord  = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1].text;
        Session *LoginSession = [[Session alloc]init];
        [LoginSession setUserName:userName];
        [LoginSession setPassword:passWord];
    }
```

So for now nothing that should not work. Now I want send my credentials with my get request

```
   Session *LoginSession = [[Session alloc]init];   
    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[LoginSession UserName],   [LoginSession Password]];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but my UserName as well as Password is always empty.. I really don't know why ...

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a singleton:

```
+(Session *)getSession
```

But you don't use it:

```
Session *LoginSession = [[Session alloc]init];
```

which should be:

```
Session *LoginSession = [Session getSession];
```

Comment: emmm what ? can you explain me that bit more ...I dont get it

Comment: @Niko.K OK, added the correct line.  You have created the singleton mechanism, but you are not using it.

Comment: @Niko.K then you should probably **think** about it. You don't use the session getter (`[Session getSession]`) but you always allocate a new instance of it. **Programming is no magic.** The fact that you implemented a singleton doesn't mean that it will **guess your intents** and **automatically do the right thing...**

Comment: @user3477950 thanks your very much for this explanation. and ofc Droppy thanks for providing me the right solution.I just dont see why my question gets allot of down votes

Comment: @Niko.K Your question should not be getting any downvotes; it contained enough detail for me to answer it and was well formatted.  Therefore it deserves upvotes for that reason alone.  The reason you get downvotes is probably because many people who frequent this site are emotionally challenged.